# Converting to vertex form, where coefficient of $w^2$ cannot be factored out

Tags: algebra-precalculus, completing-the-square

I need help on converting this to vertex form:

$$12w^2 + 13w + 3$$

I have tried finding examples online, but every time I find an example where $x^2$ has a coefficient, it is always able to be factored out.   I can't do that here because the $13w$ would not factor out cleanly.  I did even try that.  I was able to get the factored form of $(12)\left(w+\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(w+\frac{3}{4}\right)$, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get this into vertex form.  I assume that I am supposed to be completing the square, since that is what the chapter was primarily about, but I really just cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: Factor out the $12$. Doesn't matter whether it factors out "cleanly" - factor it out. Then complete the square on what's left - you get $12((w-a)^2+k)$.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried to do that as well, but when I factored it out I got $12(w^2+\frac{13}{12}w+\frac{1}{4})$.   I then added $\frac{11}{12}w$ and $\frac{3}{4}$ to both sides to get $y=(w+1)^2-\frac{11}{12}w-\frac{3}{4}$, but this is not the end product I need.   By plotting the equation on desmos, I know the vertex is not $(-1,\frac{3}{4})$, so I am lost.

Comment: _Why_ did you add and subtract those two things? That's not how completing the square works. _Complete the square_ for the polynomial $w^2+13/12 w+1/4$. How to do that is in the book.

Comment: Hint: what number is half-way between $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$12w^2+13w+3=12(w^2+\frac{13w}{12}+\frac{1}{4})=12((w+\frac{13}{24})^2-\frac{25}{576}).$

To get the $\frac{13}{24}$, find $(\frac{13}{12 \cdot 2})^2$ and add and subtract it from the expression. In general, when completing the square, find $\frac{b^2}{2a}$ and add and subtract it from the expression.

$$12(w^2+\frac{13w}{12}+\frac{169}{576}-\frac{169}{576}+\frac{1}{4})=12((w+\frac{13}{24})^2-\frac{25}{576})=12(w+\frac{13}{24})^2-\frac{25}{48}$$

Comment: Wouldn't those terms simply cancel out leaving us what we started with?

Comment: Yes, but if our goal is to write the expression in vertex form, it is advantageous to choose a number that is equal to $(\frac{b}{2})^2$. This allows us to rearrange the function in the form $m((x-k)^2+h)$ by creating a perfect square inside the expression.

Comment: Okay...I think I kind of follow here, but I get $12((w+\frac{6.5}{12})^2)-\frac{169}{576}+\frac{1}{4})=12((w+\frac{6.5}{12})^2)-\frac{25}{576})$, which is the correct k, but the wrong h....I'm sorry to be so dense, but this is just not clicking.

Comment: I figured out that $({25}{576})(12)$ gives the correct y-coordinate for the vertex, but how would I know that I need to multiple the "h" value by the coefficient to get the value for the vertex, but not the "k" value?  Is this just a standard thing that would always be true?

Comment: To get the correct $h$, note that you want to find $\sqrt{\frac{169}{576}}$ because that number squared gives $\frac{169}{576}$ AND also $2\sqrt{\frac{169}{576}}=\frac{13}{12}$, the coefficient for $w$ in the original expression.

Comment: The expression is set up very nicely to find the vertex. For an expression in vertex form $m(x-k)^2+mh$, the vertex is simply $(k, mh)$. Let $k=\frac{-13}{24}$ and $mh= \frac{-25}{48}$. Note that for $k$, the negative sign is flipped because it's a positive in the expression.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I see now that I was not distributing the m properly and that is why I was not getting it.  I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: No problem, glad my answer could help.

Answer (score 0):

Lets continue with your answer
$$\begin{array}{lll}
12w^2+13w+3&=&12(w+\frac{1}{3})(w+\frac{3}{4})\\
&=&12(w+\frac{8}{24})(w+\frac{18}{24})\\
&=&12(w+\frac{13}{24}-\frac{5}{24})(w+\frac{13}{24}+\frac{5}{24})\\
&=&12(\color{blue}{(w+\frac{13}{24})}-\frac{5}{24})(\color{blue}{(w+\frac{13}{24})}+\frac{5}{24})\\
\end{array}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't.   The way you have broken out the terms makes me think I should factor the one or both of the fractions out, i.e. $$(12)(\frac{13}{24})(w-\frac{5}{24})(w+\frac{5\24}$$, which is so close to being a perfect square, but the signs are flipped.

Comment: @Fred reviewing the Distributive Property would be very helpful here. Clearly, we have a difference of squares. Just expand the expression to $12[(w+\frac{13}{24})^2 - (\frac{5}{24})^2]$